# QML - How to style ChartView/ValueAxis

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to some styling on QML ChartView diagram. This is how it currently looks:
[image]

But I need it to look more like this, with bigger dots on the points where data was actually entered:
[image]

Is there any way to style it like this or similar using QML? My code looks like this:

```
ChartView {
            id: chartView

            title: cbProblem.currentText
            titleFont: Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 250
            legend.visible: false
            antialiasing: true
            visible: isTrendlineVisible()

            axes: [
                ValueAxis {
                    id: axisX
                    min: parseInt(cbKW.currentText) - 4
                    max: parseInt(cbKW.currentText)
                    tickCount: 5
                    labelFormat: "%i "
                    labelsFont: Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
                },
                ValueAxis {
                    id: axisY
                    min: 0
                    max: 0
                    tickCount: 9
                    labelFormat: "%i "
                    labelsFont: Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
                }
            ]
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you probably need [XYSeries.pointsVisible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-xyseries.html#pointsVisible-prop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScatterSeries` near your main Series.

Like this:

```
LineSeries {
  id: splineSery
  axisX: myAxisX
  axisY: myAxisY
  width: 3
  name:"spline"
  useOpenGL: true
  color: "black"
}
ScatterSeries {
  id: mainObjectsScatterSery
  axisX: myAxisX
  axisY: myAxisY
  useOpenGL: true
  markerSize: 10
  name:"Scatter"
  color: "green";
}
```

- Note: you need to append your data in scatter and line series